# JSF datatable filtering: Placeholders

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-2, primefaces, placeholder

Since not all of our users are guaranteed to support the HTML 5 placeholder attribute, I was trying to build a workaround for it in JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var searchInColumn = $('#searchInColumn').text();
    $(".ui-widget-glossary-editor-column-filter").on('focus', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.val() == searchInColumn) {
            $this.val('');
            $this.css('color', '#444444');
        }
    }).on('blur', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.val() == '') {
            $this.val(searchInColumn);
            $this.css('color', '#c9c9c9');
        }
    }).blur();
});
```

While that works as it's supposed to, this now of course poses the problem that an actual (localized) text is present in the input text field, triggering the datatable filter. Can I somehow intercept the PrimeFaces datatable filtering in order to treat this localized placeholder text as an empty string?

Thanks for your suggestions and best regards

Pascal

Comment: isn't your `searchInColumn` input holds already localized text from some bundle ? show `$('#searchInColumn')` code...

Comment: $('#searchInColumn') holds a hidden label text localized by JSF, yes. That allows me to have a localized JSF text available in JavaScript without having to launch a separate AJAX request. The problem is that I want to keep datatable from filtering for placeholder values.

Comment: you mean you *placeholder* being interpreted as value and sent to server ? if so you better use http://code.google.com/p/jq-watermark/wiki/Instructions to apply the watermark properly...

Comment: That actually did the trick. I did use another jquery plugin (HTML5 placeholder plugin version 1.01), but the watermark was misplaced. This, however, seems to work properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you placeholder being interpreted as value and sent to server ?

If so you better use [jq-watermark](http://code.google.com/p/jq-watermark/wiki/Instructions) to apply the watermark properly...